# Crystal Reports. How to to extract only numbers before hyphen

Tags: crystal-reports, report

We have a number field in our Database called" {PO_TEMP_PO_HEADER.PO_Number}that contains numbers in the following format:

5418-4
1247-2
9134-1

I only want to display the numbers before the hyphen
5418
1247
9134

How do I do this in Crystal Reports?

I tried various formulas I found online but it always resulted in an error when saving in Crystal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Split({your.db_column}, "-")[1];`

This splits your column into an array and returns the 1st element.